# Foundation 4 - image roll-over to reveal another image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, zurb-foundation

I am new in Foundation 4, however I do have some previous experience coding. I am moving my current photography blog (www.momentaryawe.com/blog) which is based on Wordpress with a custom built theme to a custom built theme using Foundation 4.

I've manage to get pretty much everything working as I want, but I am stuck at the following. If you look at this link (http://www.momentaryawe.com/blog/a-blur-of-colours/) you will notice that the way I have it working at the moment is when someone is rolling over the image, another image will be displayed which is the original one straight from the camera. Both of these images are uploaded when the post is created. This roll-over is done with the following jQuery code:

```
$(function() { 
  $("#rolloverOriginal ul li").hover(
    function() { 
        $(this).find('p').fadeIn(); 
    },
    function() { 
        $(this).find('p').fadeOut();
    }
);
});
```

Because Foundation 4 is using Zepto which doesn't seem to have the hover option, I am stuck on how to do the same effect using Foundation 4. I have thought of maybe using Orbit for this, but unfortunately I can get it to work on roll-over.

Comment: try to use mouse over see this link: http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/

Answer (score 0):

You can just skip zepto if you want and use jQuery. If you're using this code, then just change it to include the jquery file or use a CDN:

```
<!-- Check for Zepto support, load jQuery if necessary -->
<script>
  document.write('<script src=/js/vendor/'
    + ('__proto__' in {} ? 'zepto' : 'jquery')
    + '.js><\/script>');
</script>
```

Becomes:

```
<!-- Check for Zepto support, load jQuery if necessary -->
<script>
  document.write('<script src=/js/vendor/jquery.js><\/script>');
</script>
```

Or a CDN version:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.js"></script>
```

Because of the lack of browser support for zepto I tend to use jquery.

Updated: I've included jquery v1.10.1 but `hover` isn't supported, so instead change that code to use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`.

```
$(function() { 
  $("#rolloverOriginal ul li")
    .on('mouseenter', function() { 
        $(this).find('p').fadeIn(); 
    })
    .on('mouseleave', function() { 
        $(this).find('p').fadeOut();
    });
});
```